# General iteratively merge of pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I like to merge iteratively several data frames into one big one. The following situation could happen then:

DF12 (that was generated by merging two data frames: one with col1=a, col2=c and the other with col1=b but no col2 entry):

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | c |
| b | NaN |

DF3:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| b | d |

When I use df = pd.merge(df12,df3,how='outer') I get:

DF:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | c |
| b | NaN |
| b | d |

Using df=pd.merge(df12,df3, how='outer', on='col1') I get:

DF:

| col1 | col2_x | col2_y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | NaN |
| b | NaN | d |

But I want to have it like this:

DF:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | c |
| b | d |

this would mean, I need to use a pd.replace() or pd.update() instead of a merge.
My problem is, that in reality I do have thousands of rows and columns, I could have several data frames to be merged, the columns and rows do only overlap partially, so a .sort followed by .update does not help.
Is the only way to run through all rows and columns and find cells to be replaced (which would be very! slow) or is there any faster way? Something like
df = pd.merge(df12,df3,how='outer', 'make result as small as possible by replacing NaNs if possible') ?

Comment: e is coming from where in your expected output?

Comment: sorry, the tables where ok in pre-view, but not here. Need to insert a currage return before a table.